# Excel Measure not showing all Table Columns

Tags: excel, powerpivot, measure

I'm trying to create a measure in excel but my autocomplete doesn't give me all colums in the referenced table. Any idea why ?

[image]

I want to use the "gemiddelde van Maand Index" (Average of Month index) but it's not available. When i just type it like it should be there is a red line beneath.

[image]

My relationships are OK i guess:

[image]

Comment: Are you referencing a measure or a column name. It looks like you are referencing a measure, try to reference it without a table name. 
You can do this by typing the square bracket "[".

Comment: I'm referencing a calculated column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference a field Excel is calculating when you drop it in the field list (Excel chooses: average/sum/count depending on fieldtype). You have to create the measure first.

> Average Month Index:=AVERAGE('Calendar'[Maand Index])

Answer (score 1):

This is the reference syntaxis:

'TableName'[ColumnName]

In your table i dont see a column named "gemiddelde van Maand Index", but there is a "Maand Index"

Try: 'Calendar'[Maand Index]

Comment: Excel creates this automatically (Average of Maand Index).